# My NVidia GPU runs processes that take unreasonable amount of memory

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xorg

I have a new laptop with NVidia RTX 2070 GPU and Ubuntu 18.04 installed that I'm using for Machine Learning. I noticed that my GPU goes OOM (out of memory) a bit too often. And in fact when I type `nvidia-smi` that's what I get:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 440.64.00    Driver Version: 440.64.00    CUDA Version: 10.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce RTX 2070    On   | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   45C    P8     6W /  N/A |    642MiB /  7982MiB |      3%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      1209      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                            72MiB |
|    0      1237      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                          52MiB |
|    0      1565      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                           329MiB |
|    0      1693      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                         178MiB |
|    0     14702      G   /usr/lib/firefox/firefox                       2MiB |
|    0     14814      G   /usr/lib/firefox/firefox                       2MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I have `Xorg` and `gnome-shell` running on GPU and taking and unreasonable amount of memory (in my opinion, correct me if I'm wrong). I also had Atom open before, and it took way too much memory too.

I have some questions at this point:

1. Why are these processes running on GPU? Aren't they supposed to run on CPU?
2. How can I force them to be run on CPU? And is it advisable to do it?
3. Is there any of these processes I should `kill`?

Answer (score 0):

Xorg and gnome-shell run on dgpu when you have performance mode turned on. I had a similar problem before. I went to Nvidia X server settings and there on the PRIME Profiles menu, I set NVIDIA (On demand) instead of NVIDIA (Performance mode). My issue was fixed after a reboot.